# how to pass the variable in segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

i have defined variable in GroupView.h

```
@interface GroupView()
{

  NSMutableArray *chatrooms;
}

@end

@implementation GroupView
```

Now i want to pass this variable in segue

```
@interface FriendsViewController ()

 @end

@implementation FriendsViewController


 else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showGroupView"]) {
          GroupView *groupView  = (GroupView *)segue.destinationViewController;
          groupView.chatrooms = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:chatrooms];
  }
```

i know that chatrooms has to be property in header file to code this way but it is not

So is there any way to use this variable in segue.

Thanks for help.

Comment: sorry i wrote totally opposite my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chatrooms` defined as an ivar like you have done is accessed using `->` notation:

```
groupView->chatrooms = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:chatrooms]
```

This is generally discouraged, though. You should use a property instead:

```
@interface GroupView
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *chatrooms;
@end
```

Incidentally, if you're using an `NSMutableArray`, that indicates that you want to modify the element list of the array directly and not just replace the array wholesale. If you only ever want to replace the array with a whole new array every time, I suggest using `NSArray` instead.

Another point to make here is that you're attempting to cast the object held at `segue.destinationViewController` as a `GroupView`. You have either named a `UIViewController` subclass in a very misleading way, or you are not accessing the `GroupView` as a correct member of the `UIViewController` that is returned to you.

Comment: i made changes to my post pls check it.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you are not building the SDK or something. You don't really have a better reason not to expose it in the header file. However, you can expose the property in the extension and declare a private property in the host class(It's really not able to pass if you just declare a local variable). For example, You have a extension called `GroupView+Helper`. So, you can pass it into the property exposed in the extension. And then internally translate into the `GroupView`.

In **GroupView.m**:

```
@interface GroupView
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *chatrooms;
@end
```

In **GroupView+Helper.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *internalChatrooms;
```

Also, you need to import the **GroupView+Helper** in the **GroupView**.
It will make your `chatrooms` private and internalChatrooms protected.